# How to split a column into three columns based on separator and/or position in r

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have this fake data set with a column named `location`.

```
data.1 <-read.csv(text = "
location
01-Q2-Locate of este (TT)
02-Q2-Green River (OG)
01-Q1-Agabe (PS)
")
```

I need to partition the `location` column into three columns named `code`, `name`, and `region`.

This is my intended outcome:

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data.1.new <- data.1 %>%
  tidyr::separate(location, c("code", "name", "region"), extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)
```

The outcome I am getting is this:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to separate to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution:

**EXPLANATION** (asked by the OP)

1. First `str_extract`: See [demo1](https://regex101.com/r/zCY4r0/1).
2. Second `str_extract`: See [demo2](https://regex101.com/r/C1TId4/1).
3. Third `str_extract`: See [demo3](https://regex101.com/r/iy9Frx/1).

```r
library(tidyverse)

data.1 %>% 
  mutate(code = str_extract(location, "^\\d+-\\D\\d+"),
         name = str_extract(location, "(?<=-)\\D+(?=\\s\\()"),
         zegion = str_extract(location, "(?<=\\().*(?=\\))"))

#>                    location  code           name zegion
#> 1 01-Q2-Locate of este (TT) 01-Q2 Locate of este     TT
#> 2    02-Q2-Green River (OG) 02-Q2    Green River     OG
#> 3          01-Q1-Agabe (PS) 01-Q1          Agabe     PS
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on the logic of the statement to extract the text?

Comment: Please, @GiuseppePetri, see my updated answer.

Comment: This is so much helpful! Thanks so much for both the response and the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

```
data.1 %>%
+   extract(location, c('code', 'name', 'region'), '(.*)-([^(]+) \\((.*)\\)')

   code           name region
1 01-Q2 Locate of este     TT
2 02-Q2    Green River     OG
3 01-Q1          Agabe     PS
```